# match a dd:dd:dd and do something in bash

Tags: bash, parsing

I am trying to match some digits like "**38:00:00**" from **device_output file,**  collected from sftp server and put some if condition as sending  mail with the that output. I did something but I want to have something more advanced code there beside **egrep ":"** :))

**device_output file**

```
<style>
table,td{blbalba}
</style>
Device Name     Ip Address  Flaps   ASN Uptime
Nexus           182.168.2.2 0       300 38:00:20
ASA Firewall    182.168.2.3 0       400 44:01:20
ASR CUBE        182.168.2.4 0       400 22w02d
VMWare          182.168.2.5 0       400 12:03:20
Nexus           182.168.2.5 0       400 12w03d
Nexus           182.168.2.5 0       400 12:03:20
```

**bash script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

#Variables 
SFTPHOSTNAME="192.168.1.1"
SFTPUSERNAME="user"
SFTPPASSWORD="pass"
FOLDER="/home/$USER/ftp"
#SFTP CONNECTION
output=$(sshpass -p $SFTPPASSWORD sftp $SFTPUSERNAME@$SFTPHOSTNAME << !
    cd $FOLDER
    get device_status
 exit
!);

#!/bin/bash
if egrep ":" device_output ; then

          cat device_output | egrep ":|style|table|Device"  | mailx -s "$(echo -e "BGP Sessions Uptime Issue \nContent-Type: text/html")" -r from_user@yah to_user@yah
else
        exit 0
fi
```

Comment: updated my collected file(device_output)..sorry

Comment: I don't how mentioned *some digits like "38:00:00"* are used in your current code

Comment: grep any digit with colon like : dd:dd:dd, parse and output them in condition

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use egrep this way :

```
egrep ".:..:.."
```

which would match `1:00:00` or `38:00:00`

or, if you care about the digits :

`egrep "[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]|[0-9]:"` would also match